# logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() En fragmento se cierra aplicación

Tags: android, android-fragment

tengo 2 botones y 1 text view en este caso el texto no lo puse en el codigo pero al abrir la aplicacion y llamar al fragmento en cuestion desde un menu drawable se cierra la aplicacion ya no se de que forma poner los botones dentro del fragmento.

```
public class DesconectarFragment extends Fragment {
private SessionHandler session;
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    session = new SessionHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    User user = session.getUserDetails();

    //infoSessionText = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.InfoSessionText);

    //infoSessionText.setText(""+user.getFullName()+", tu sesión expira el "+user.getSessionExpiryDate());

    Button logoutBtn = root.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         session.logoutUser();
         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
    );
    Button cancelarBtn = root.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);
    logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    );
    return root;
}
}
```

Este es el error que sale:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.innodevtech.ui.desconectar.DesconectarFragment.onCreateView(DesconectarFragment.java:33)

Ya se que esta indicando que los objetos son null pero si estan en el layout y los reconoce a medida que voy escribiendo el codigo.

Comment: Idem with text viewççjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference; View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        session = new SessionHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        User user = session.getUserDetails();

        TextView infoSessionText = root.findViewById(R.id.InfoSessionText);
        infoSessionText.setText(""+user.getFullName()+", tu sesión expira el "+user.getSessionExpiryDate());

Comment: Para empezar, decirte que esta página es para escribir en español. El error es muy claro, estás intentando ejecutar la función setOnClickListener sobre un objeto null. Así que el botón debe ser null. comprueba que findViewById te está retornando el objeto correcto. Por otro lado, defines dos botones logoutBtn y cancelarBtn, pero el setOnClickListener lo ejecutas las dos veces sobre logoutBtn. Entiendo que eso no es correcto.

Comment: los elementos me los identifica según voy agregando código.

Comment: Pues es obvio que findViewById no te está funcionando. Y dado que solo recibe un parámetro, parece que este no sea correcto. ¿El identificador del botón coincide con el que aparece en el xml? ¿Está ese botón en el xml del layout de este fragmento? Por otro lado, lo de ejecutar el setOnClickListener sobre el mismo objeto dos veces tampoco está bien hecho.

Comment: pero el setOnClickListener lo ejecutas las dos veces sobre logoutBtn, cierto ya lo corregi, pero aun asi me sigue saliendo ese error.

Comment: Pon un punto de ruptura en la línea en la que ejecutas findViewById, depura y comprueba que los botones están a null. Si están a null, revisa los id de los botones en los xml y que estén en el mismo layout fragment_inicio

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta, el idioma oficial del sitio es español, revisa por favor [ask] para que agregues detalles a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Listo perdon pense que estaba en stack en ingles. jaja

Answer (score 0):

El problema es simplemente que la referencia de alguno de los botones no existe en el archivo `fragment_inicio.xml`.

```
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    ...
    ...
    Button logoutBtn = root.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    ...
    ...
    Button cancelarBtn = root.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);
    ...
    ...
```

Asegura que los botones con id `btnLogout` y `btnCancelar` existen dentro de `fragment_inicio.xml`, incluso puedes tener otro archivo `fragment_inicio.xml` para otra densidad en el cual no se encuentran los botones .

Con respecto a tu comentario:

> Ya se que esta indicando que los objetos son null pero si estan en el
>   layout y los reconoce a medida que voy escribiendo el codigo.

En realidad pueden no estar los botones en el layout, pero por el hecho de encontrarse en el proyecto estos pueden ser reconocidos, pero esto no asegura que se encuentren en el layout `fragment_inicio.xml`.

Comment: si estan los elementos en el layout

Comment: Revisa si tienes otro fragment_inicio.xml , si no es así ¿puedes agregar el archivo  fragment_inicio.xml a tu pregunta?